# Looking for a short term solution to improve website performance with additional server

Tags: php, mysql, performance, optimization, cluster-analysis

I am working with a small team to run an internal website running with PHP 5.3.9, MySQL 5.0.77. All the files and database are hosted on a dedicated Linux machine with the following configuration:

Intel Xeon E5450 8 CPU cores @3.00GHz,
2992.498 MHz,
Cache 6148 KB,
Cent OS – Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4

We started small and then the database got bigger and now the website performance degraded significantly. We often get server space overrun, mysql overloaded with too many calls, etc. We don't have much experience dealing with these issues. We recently got another server that we were thinking to use to improve performance. Since it has better configuration, some of us wanted to completely move everything to the new machine. But I am trying to find out how we can utilize both machine for optimized performance. I found options such as MySQL clustering, Load balancer, etc. I was wondering if I could get any suggestion for this situation "How to utilize two machines in short term for best performance", that would be great. By short term we are looking for something that we can deploy in a month or so.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try to move your MySQL server to a separate machine. You can add another web server if you store the sessions in a centralized store (like the database) instead of plain files on the server. You'll need to write a custom session handler for this. If you have multiple web servers, don't forget to use load balancing. Also try caching the result of your SQL queries (in memcached or Redis), that can significantly improve performace.

Comment: Yeah, the easiest improvement will be to run your mysql server on the old machine and your web server on the new machine.

Answer (score 3):

Making the website to run on two servers with some kind of load balancing is way harder then you would expect...

My approach to the problem would be to get someone on the team to look into the problems related with the database, like SLOW QUERIES (MySQL can be configured to log any queries that took more then certain amount of time to finish), then to check the reasons for that (using MySQL EXPLAIN). Few indexes might fix the critical failing points and give you time to come up with a solid, long-term solution. If the database is very badly optimized, this could even remove the need of doing anything else for now!

You could move MySQL to another machine in the same network, so you could separate the web server load and the DB load.

Consider caching some parts of the data that don't change too often, but are loaded on every request on the website. Memcached, redis cache, file caching, anything would do.

Another short term solution (and cheap, compared to developers time) would be to replace the HDD with SSD, especially if you have queries where the disk has to seek a lot. In my personal experience that could make dramatic difference.

Answer (score 1):

- You're using MySQL 5.0.77, which was released in January 2009.  There have been vast improvements in the performance and scalability of MySQL.  You should upgrade to the current version, which is  5.5.28 as of this writing.  That alone should give you a lot of performance improvement.
- You should analyze your queries to make sure you have well-chosen indexes.  This is a crucial step to improving performance.  See my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) for some tips on how to do this.
- InnoDB is almost always a better choice for storage engine than MyISAM in modern versions of MySQL.  Always test to be sure, because there are some edge cases where MyISAM may still run faster.  Though InnoDB has many more tuning parameters, and it's important to set them well because the defaults are much too low for good performance.  You can get some insight for tuning configuration parameters for InnoDB in my presentation [MySQL 5.5 Guide to InnoDB Status](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/mysql-55-guide-to-innodb-status).
- You should put the database on a dedicated server, separate from your applications.  The best single improvement to performance is usually increasing the amount of memory you devote to the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` (assuming you use InnoDB storage engine).
- As @Veseliq suggests, upgrading to an SSD drive for your data directory is a great way to get a boost in performance.
- Configure MySQL's `tmpdir` to use your SSD drive, too.
- If you can't get an SSD drive, the next best thing is a RAID controller with a write-back cache.
- Set the MySQL configuration `skip_name_resolve` to eliminate dependency on DNS reverse lookups when applications connect.  If you do this, you need to grant SQL privileges by IP address, not by hostname.
- Various other Linux tuning improvements:

  - Use **XFS** filesystem on your data diretory, not the Linux default of ext3.
  - Mount filesystems with **noatime** option.
  - Use the **deadline** disk I/O scheduler, not the Linux default of cfq.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest first step is to separate your database and front-end application processes, putting these on to different machines. This usually lets you allocate considerably more memory to the `mysqld` process through modifications to `my.cnf` settings.

As always, update to the latest version of your stack and back-end to be sure you're taking maximum advantage of your hardware.

Pay close attention to the database calls running on your system and see if there's any way to speed these up. `EXAMINE` can often show the execution strategy for any given `SELECT` call, as an example, and will reveal where you have missing indexes, often the biggest performance drag of all. If you're getting hit with "table scan" or "using filesort" you're basically dead in the water on large datasets. You need indexes or a different schema.

The second step is to layer in more front-end application servers and add in a load-balancer of some kind. This gives you additional front-end capacity to handle load better, but also loads down your database even more.

The third step is to ensure that you're not doing any unnecessary `JOIN` operations during your `SELECT` calls. Examine what you need from the database very carefully and try and get everything from one table at a time. Tactical de-normalization is often the solution here, but with it comes sync problems if you're not careful to do this properly. Pay close attention when you're doing this and be sure you have extensive test coverage.

The fourth step is often to buffer your heavy read activity on the database by using a cache like [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) to avoid hitting the database as often. Remember that the fastest database call is the one you don't make.

There's no magic bullet, but if you do things in that order you should have a fighting chance.